# how to convert ajax post call api in angular8

Tags: php, json, angular, typescript, angular8

Client given below Ajax Post call, when i will open below PHP api file in browser then the static data is inserting correctly, now i am trying using Angular, but I am not able to understand how to convert this below call into component.ts and service

```
        <?php
    //creating payload parameters:
    $classTitle = 'Demo Class on 3rd April, 2020';
    $classInfo = 'This is a demo class scheduled to understand API';
    $classDateTime = '2020-11-12 11:30 AM';
    $timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
    $classDuration = 15;
    $classRecording = 'yes';
    $classAutoStart = false;
    $recordingAutoStart = false;
    $classVideoRes = 720;


    /*xyz.com*/
    $apiKey = '12345';
    $secretKey = '12345';

    // Create token header as a JSON string
    $header = json_encode(['alg' => 'HS256','typ' => 'JWT']); // ensure to place first alg part and next typ part

    // Create token payload as a JSON string
    $payload = json_encode(['classTitle' => $classTitle ,'classInfo' => $classInfo ,'classDateTime' => $classDateTime ,'timezone' => $timezone ,'classDuration' => $classDuration ,'classRecording' => $classRecording ,'classAutoStart' => $classAutoStart ,'recordingAutoStart' => $recordingAutoStart ,'classVideoRes' => $classVideoRes ,'apiKey' => $apiKey]);

    // Encode Header to Base64Url String
    $base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));

    // Encode Payload to Base64Url String
    $base64UrlPayload = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($payload));

    // Create Signature Hash
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $secretKey , true);

    // Encode Signature to Base64Url String
    $base64UrlSignature = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($signature));

    // creating JWT token variable
    $jwt_token = $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload . "." . $base64UrlSignature;

    // creating authorization varibale
    $authorization = 'Bearer '.$jwt_token;

    ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
         url: 'https://xyz/client/schedule',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "apiKey": "12345"
        }),
        dataType : 'json',
        headers: {
        'authorization': '<?php echo $authorization; ?>'
        },
        success: function(retval)
        {
        // alert(retval);
        console.log(retval);
        // var success = retval.success;
        }
        });
    </script>
```

I have updated Question and added after two replied answer

Below is my model class

```
export class Schedule1 {

classTitle: string;
classInfo: string;
classDateTime: string;
timezone: string;
classDuration: number;
classRecording:string;
classAutoStart: boolean;
recordingAutoStart: boolean;
classVideoRes: number;
    
   constructor() {
    
      
   }

  }
```

Below is component.ts on button click passing static values

```
import { Schedule1 } from '../Models/Schedule1.model'


   Schedule1: Schedule1 = new Schedule1();

    addSchedule(scheduleForm: NgForm): void {

    //static data parameter passing
    this.Schedule1.classTitle='hi Class on 3rd April, 2020';
    this.Schedule1.classInfo= 'This is a demo class scheduled to understand API';
    this.Schedule1.classDateTime= '2020-11-12 11:30 AM';
    this.Schedule1.timezone= 'Asia/Kolkata';
    this.Schedule1.classDuration= 15;
    this.Schedule1.classRecording= 'yes';
    this.Schedule1.classAutoStart= false;
    this.Schedule1.recordingAutoStart= false;
    this.Schedule1.classVideoRes= 720;


    //const data = JSON.stringify(this.Schedule1);
    const data = { 
    apiKey: "dcbf187d-bdfe-431b-8f60-fa19bf51cd85", 
    data:  JSON.stringify(this.Schedule1)
    } 

    this.subscription = this.userSvc
    .fetchData("https: //xyz.com/client/schedule", data)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
    // Data on Success
    console.log("data", data);
    },
    error => {
    console.log("error", error);
    }
    );

    }
```

Below is service.ts

```
  fetchData(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = {
    
    Authorization: "Bearer "+"1234",
     "My-Custom-Header": "foobar",
    contentType: "application/json"
    };

   return this.http.post(url, data, {
    headers
    });
   }
```

in console getting this error.

[image]

Comment: You can't use server-side with angular SPA like `<?php echo $authorization; ?>'` however, the rest should be no issue. Are you using `server-side` views?

Comment: I have updated full question. @Basheer kharoti

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan your api in php?

Comment: Client given api in php, now i am converting into angular throught angular passing. @Kantivekariya

Comment: if i call directly php api in angular then its not working thats why i am converting into angular to call api. @Kantivekariya

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan you need to pass the valid token in api.

Comment: from where i get valid token?. client php api run in browser then its working and inserting to server but my angular code is not working and 2 days back i called direct php file into angular but that is not working thats why i am converting @Kantivekariya

Comment: It's helpful try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917889/passing-a-php-variable-to-angular

Comment: I know how to pass parameter to php script that is not working. @Kantivekariya

Comment: As it is calling php file from angular then also not inserting into server. @Kantivekariya

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTTP request is pretty simple in Angular. Below are the steps you need to follow:

Step 1:

import the `HttpClientModule` in your app module like this:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
imports: [ HttpClientModule ]
```

Step 2:

Create a service for your application where you will store all the HTTP request calls.

**NOTE: This part is not necessary as you can do HTTP calls directly in your component but for best practice and good structure this should be followed**

So for this step, import `HttpClient` either in your service (if you have created) or in your component and then do like this below:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

createExamCategory(data) {
  return this.http.post<{ message: string }>(this.url + '/category/create_exam', data);
}
```

Let me explain the `createExamCategory()` method.
The parameter `data` is the value that is coming from your HTML or any source. And this `data` will be passed in `POST` request.
The next line is as I am explaining with service I have just returned the call and will `subscribe` to it in the component.
The `<{ message: string }>` is the response that I am getting from the API request. If you are not sure what response you are getting you can just keep it as `<any>` and Angular will decide the type of response.
Then in the `post` method (this method is coming from `HttpClient` declared above) we have 2 pass to parameters by default & the third parameter which is `HttpHeader` is optional. The 2 parameters are:

1. URL OF the API.
2. The request body data for the `POST` request.

So that's all from the calling side now coming to the subscription part:

If you are directly writing the above part in component then continue with `.subscribe()`. Now for the service part:

Step 1:
Import the service:

```
import { SampleService } from 'sample.service';

constructor(private service: SampleService) { }

// Do the call where it is required. I am doing in a normal method

httpMethod() {
  this.service.createExamCategory(data).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response); // This is the API response
  });
}
```

**Interceptor**

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Service } from 'service.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router, private service: Service) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
            const cloned = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
            });
            return next.handle(cloned).pipe(
                catchError((err, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (err.status == 401)) 
                    {
                        this.adminAuthService.clearAuthData();
                        this.router.navigate(['required route path']);
                        alert('Session Timeout !! Login Again');
                        return of(err as any);
                    }
                    throw err;
                })
            );
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Here what I have done is while login/authentication I have stored the generated JWT token by the backend service in session and validated if the API url is valid or not.

After doing this in **app.module.ts** specify the interceptor in the `providers` like this:

```
providers: [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

Hoping this will help you

Comment: the third parameter only the issue to pass can you write with third option also as above question JWT token passing with apikey please check the above question code in php code. @Avishek Datta Ray

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan the third option I meant about the headers part. I am updating the answer have a look at it. What I will do is rather than passing JWT here use an interceptor which will verify if the API url is valid with respect to the JWT token

Comment: i have not more experience in angular recently started angular, please update fully answer or can we chat now. @Avishek Datta Ray

Comment: I struck since 10 days please help me, i need to submit parameters to server, which one is easy that update your answer. @Avishek Datta Ray

Comment: https://github.com/barefacedbear/mean-practice

Here is a sample project for angular though the backend is in Node this can help you much

Comment: dear author, please accept the answer if you found it helpful with respect to the question  that can help many folks out here

Answer (score 0):

You can Create service Like and call in component.

`services.ts`

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})

export class UserService{

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

 let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ''
 });

  public getData(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: headers});
  }
}
```

`components.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './services.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class Components implements OnInit {

 constructor(public userService: UserService){}

 public ngOnInit(): void {
    const data = { apiKey: "myapikey" }
    this.userService.getData(url, data).subscribe((res)=>{
     code...
    })
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Please can you call this method in component.ts?.@Kanti vekariya

Comment: how to pass api key. @anti vekariya

Comment: The API key you can pass in data like `{ apiKey: "myapikey" }`

Comment: where i have to pass api key can you add that code also. @Kanti vekariya

Comment: Inside component.ts you just add const data = { apiKey: "myapikey" } i update code you cn check.

Comment: is it helpful? @mohdmazharkhan

Comment: i am checking will update you, but how to pass object on button click pass parameters object whre i have to pass, i have object call schedule whre i have to add this object. @Kanti vekariya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224184/discussion-between-mohd-mazhar-khan-and-kanti-vekariya).

Comment: @Kantivekariya `Forbidden error` means that you are not authorized to access that URL. Pass the valid `Authorization` header rather

Answer (score 0):

create a service like below.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ScheduleDataService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchData(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: "Bearer my-token",
      "My-Custom-Header": "foobar",
      contentType: "application/json"
    };

    return this._http.post(url, data, {
      headers
    });
  }
}
```

then you can call this service in your component like below.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { ScheduleDataService } from "./schedule-data.service.ts";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  private subscription;
  constructor(private _scheduleDataService: ScheduleDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._scheduleDataService
      .fetchData("https://xyz/client/schedule", {
        apiKey: "myapikey"
      })
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // Data on Success
          console.log("data", data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("error", error);
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: how to pass parameters object to post data in above component.ts. @Piyush Jain

Comment: 2nd argument of fetch data method

Comment: const data = { 
  apiKey: "myip", 
  data: this.Schedule 
  } 
  this.subscription = this.userSvc.fetchData("https://xyz/client/schedule", data ) 
  .subscribe( 
  data => { 
  // Data on Success 
  console.log("data", data); 
  }, 
  error => { 
  console.log("error", error); 
  } 
  ); 
  
  
  } is this correct. @Piyush Jain

Comment: What is the value of this.schedule ?

Comment: can we chat now. @Piyush Jain

Comment: I have updated question please check and confirm for live chat. @Piyush Jain